# How does Vista Recycle bin work?

Tags: python, windows-vista, recycle-bin

I am trying to write a python module to move files to the 'Recycle Bin' on both Mac and PC.

Is there a way, only from the commandline (and yes, I mean using absloutly no C#/C++/etc) to move a file into the Recycle Bin, and have it appear as a file trashed by drag and drop (or deleted via SHFileOperation, etc).

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164(VS.85).aspx) function or, on Vista, the [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771(VS.85).aspx) interface (as pointed out by gix below).

From the remarks on `SHFileOperation`:

> When used to delete a file, SHFileOperation permanently deletes the file unless you set the FOF_ALLOWUNDO flag in the fFlags member of the SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure pointed to by lpFileOp. Setting that flag sends the file to the Recycle Bin. If you want to simply delete a file and guarantee that it is not placed in the Recycle Bin, use DeleteFile.

Comment: Why are you describing a Win32/COM method of doing this, when the question asks for a Python way, explicitly excluding C#, C++, etc?

Comment: There surely must be a way of executing system calls from Python. If not, then it's a broken tool to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

Moving files to Windows' Recycle Bin is a Shell operation. Shell operations are run via COM. For older Windows versions there is the [SHFileOperation interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164(VS.85).aspx). Since Vista there is the new [IFileOperation interface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I have written a [Python library that does precisely that](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Send2Trash/). You might want to check it out.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like [this mailing list entry](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-June/091800.html) might help you.